# Как отобразить все стили сайта на React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Как отобразить или сохранить все стили элементов сайта созданного на React?
Через DevTools можно увидеть стиль отдельного элемента, но источник пустой тег

```
<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.2.1"></style>
```

[image: imdb]

Answer (score 0):

Стили есть в тэги style в head, если кликнуть по ссылке на которую указывает стрелка на вашем скриншоте, Вас перекинет на этот тэг в head

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

если хотите сохранить можно скопирован весь код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]